# Time period in contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development

there
I have a contract that I want to work just in a specific period and then stop working I wrote these two function but they didn't seem correct, this contract is called multiple times and I just want it works 10 min after the first call can anyone help?

````
    contract MyContract {
     uint start;
    mapping (uint => uint) public blockTime;
function addBlock public (){
   uint num++;
    blockTime[num]=block.timestamp;
// I want to know when is the first time this contract is called (from another contract)
    start=blockTime[1];

}
    function specificTime(uint event) public {
     // just work for 10 min   
    require (block.timestamp <= start + 10 minutes); 

        // some event will happen
        myEvent(event);
    }
}```
````

Comment: Your code is a mess. Please fix the indentation. What's the point in the `blockTime` if you're only using `blockTime[1]`? How exactly are you testing your code? Are you calling `addBlock` before calling `specificTime`? This question is very badly written!

Comment: Sorry for my bad english , i call addBlock first and i use just blockTime [1] and i dont need the rest of them but this contract will call multiple times and i want just to khow when is the first time to end call after 10 min. If i use blocktimestamp it give me current blocktimestamp but i want first one.

Comment: @saraafshar What problem do you have? The only problem I see is that start is always overwritten when you call addBlock, since num is set to 1.

Comment: @Ismael my question is how can i store timestamp of my fist contract call? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a mess and conceptually "off". There will be guessing about what you are trying to achieve.

> Just work for 10 minutes

If you mean "wait", then no, not like that. A contract function executes approximately instantaneously. It cannot wait (linger) and it cannot schedule something to happen in the future.

if you mean "valid until" or "functional until" then you can define a second function that someone may (or may not) call in the next phase, and it can check a deadline and decide if the request is acceptable. Roughly:

`require(block.timestamp < deadline, "too late.");`

Keep in mind that the function that sets the deadline will *have to* finish up immediately.

There are design patterns that use an admin, an "oracle" or even crowd incentives to schedule something/incentivize someone to call a function at a point in the future. Those are workarounds to create something like a scheduled task.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tnx it really helped